# delete image from sd card in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I try to select images from sd card,specific folder and show it in my gridView successfully.I have one problem.in gridview onClickListener i want to delete this image by position.strange situation.file deleted in my folder ,but gridview still showing images

```
    private void fetchGalleryImages() {
    Uri mImageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED};
    Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri, columns, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[]{"%/Download/New Folder%"}, null);
    galleryImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);//get column index
        galleryImageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));//get Image from column index
        Log.e("array path", galleryImageUrls.get(i));
    }
}
private void setUpGridView() {

    imagesAdapter = new GridView_Adapter(CustomGallery_Activity.this, galleryImageUrls, true);
    galleryImagesGridView.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
    galleryImagesGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            File file = new File(galleryImageUrls.get(position));
            if (file.exists())
            {
                file.delete();
                imagesAdapter = new GridView_Adapter(CustomGallery_Activity.this, galleryImageUrls, true);
                galleryImagesGridView.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Sorry I misateked.I added this line in OnClick

```
 galleryImageUrls.remove(position);
```

I closed app and run again but i have same problem.. I want to update my gridview

Comment: No, it is not strange ... galleryImageUrls is unchanged so what's you expected?

Comment: @Selvin i added this line  galleryImageUrls.remove(position); but when i run my app again all images still showing

Comment: Because you didn't remove it from MediaStore db/contentprovider ...

Comment: @ Selvin  I have file manager app and  i checked my folder and it's empty,but gridview still showing.. can you show me solution?

Comment: @Selvin thanks i answered myself.problem solved...

Answer (score -1):

This is correct answer.I solved myself

```
 private void setUpGridView() {

    imagesAdapter = new GridView_Adapter(CustomGallery_Activity.this, galleryImageUrls, true);
    galleryImagesGridView.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
    galleryImagesGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            File file = new File(galleryImageUrls.get(position));
            if (file.exists())
            {
                file.delete();
                deleteFileFromMediaManager(galleryImageUrls.get(position));
                galleryImageUrls.remove(position);
                imagesAdapter = new GridView_Adapter(CustomGallery_Activity.this, galleryImageUrls, true);
                galleryImagesGridView.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
            }

        }
    });
}

private void deleteFileFromMediaManager(String path) {
    try {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(CustomGallery_Activity.this, new String[] { path },
                null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        CustomGallery_Activity.this.getContentResolver()
                                .delete(uri, null, null);
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```